# NSE: After minimizing and restoring a window I get 'WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING' but not 'WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED'

Tags: windows-8.1, shell-extensions, taskbar, window-messages, window-position

If I minimize my **shell extension** folder, and then try to restore it via click in the taskbar, I get an error beep and nothing is done.

Using `Microsoft Spy++`, I reviewed the events of attempting to restore the folder and got the following:

```
<00001> 0019013C S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:021DEC48
<00002> 0019013C R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00003> 0019013C S message:0x0422 [User-defined:WM_USER+34] wParam:00200001 lParam:00000000
<00004> 0019013C R message:0x0422 [User-defined:WM_USER+34] lResult:00000001
<00005> 0019013C P message:0xC18C [Registered:"CMBActivate"] wParam:00200001 lParam:00000000
```

While for a regular window, I get the following:

```
<00001> 00190114 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0DFCE920
<00002> 00190114 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00003> 00190114 S message:0x0422 [User-defined:WM_USER+34] wParam:00200001 lParam:00000000
<00004> 00190114 R message:0x0422 [User-defined:WM_USER+34] lResult:00000001
<00005> 00190114 P message:0xC18C [Registered:"CMBActivate"] wParam:00200001 lParam:00000000
<00006> 00190114 S message:0x0425 [User-defined:WM_USER+37] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000033
<00007> 00190114 R message:0x0425 [User-defined:WM_USER+37] lResult:00000000
<00008> 00190114 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0DFCE610
<00009> 00190114 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00010> 00190114 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:0DFCE5B0
<00011> 00190114 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:0DFCE6D4
<00012> 00190114 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0DFCE610
<00013> 00190114 S WM_SIZE fwSizeType:SIZE_RESTORED nWidth:1034 nHeight:563
<00014> 00190114 R WM_SIZE
<00015> 00190114 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
```

The issue only reproduced for me on `Windows 8.1`, and not on any release prior to that.

What could be the reason `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` is not called and that `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is not called at all? As I understand, it must be called after the operation is completed, and perhaps that is the reason my window won't get restored, and I'm getting the error beep.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was with server communication under my implementation of `IExtractIconW.GetIconLocation`.

The way to resolve it was to remember which windows are minimized at a given time and for them to return some default icon location.